# ShareKit 2.0: Facebook already authenticated

Tags: ios, facebook, sharekit

I am using [ShareKit 2.0](http://www.github.com/Sharekit/Sharekit) (installed via cocoapods) to post text and image to facebook from my iOS app.

The problem is it gets stuck in an inifite loop of opening the facebook app, there it displays the autorization page for the app but with the message that it is already authorized.

I added the URL scheme for my fb id to the info.plist, I also added the app delegate methods like in the ShareKit wiki.

What can I do about this?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Same here. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: no, not yet. I figured out that the cocoapods version of ShareKit is 2 months old. Replaced the revision that it should use in the podspec file but that doesn't work as the project has undergone some major restructuring and I don't know enough about cocoapods yet to make it work ... maybe the error is fixed by now, but it's not working for me yet.

Comment: I got the same problem although I'm using the latest source code from GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was ShareKit isn't compatible with the latest Facebook iOS sdk, which was installed by cocoapods due to no version appended to the dependency. That should now be fixed, so clear your Pods and do pod install again.